# how to import org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils

Tags: java, keyword

I wanted to use isJavaKeyWord() method from JavaUtils class. Hence, I am trying to import,  import org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils;. However, I am getting error.

This the link where you can find the class details
http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/utils/JavaUtils.html

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting error as  the "import org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils; can not be resolved" .

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to add the maven dependency to your project or download the jar to be used in your project.

Jar can be found in below url.
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this.

Comment: You are welcome. Check the tick mark so that other people won't have to look into the question.